# SharePoint long path not working in Python

Tags: python, sharepoint, path

My Organization recently rearranged their SharePoint folder and now my script is not working.

I have a Python script that is reading an Excel file from SharePoint. The old path used to look like this:

```
FILE_PATH = "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/Folder1/Shared%20Documents/Project%20Files/0.%20Databases%202022/Previous%20DB%20versions%20(Not-used)/Some_Excel_File.xlsx"
```

And it was working fine. Now the path looks like this:

```
FILE_PATH = "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/MainMission/Shared%20Documents/5.%20Programme%20(projects-Files-TU)%20Department/DLLY052%20-%20EX%20Projects%20II/9.%20042%20Operational%20Documents/0.%20Databases%202022/Previous%20DB%20versions%20(Not-used)/Some_Excel_File.xlsx"
```

and I get an error when I try to open it.

```
Error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 'Open method of Workbooks class failed', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)
```

I know the issue is with the path because I copied the same file to a more simpler SharePoint path and it worked. I tried escaping and formatting using:

```
FILE_PATH = r'{0}'.format(FILE_PATH)
FILE_PATH = os.path.expandvars(FILE_PATH)
FILE_PATH = FILE_PATH.replace("%", "%%")
```

None of the above worked for me.
Thanks.

Comment: ".. *and I get an error when I try to open it*". You gotta be more specific!

Comment: Updated the post with the error message. Error goes away when using a shorter more simpler path.